# Error while executing alter table to add new column with default values as seq.nextval

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm getting below error while executing the following sql query with Oracle 11g

```
ALTER TABLE table add column_col integer DEFAULT table_seq.nextval not null;

Error report -
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax doesn't work with 11g.  It's new to 12.  You need a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TRIGGERNAME" BEFORE INSERT ON <<TABLENAME>>
FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (new."COLUMNNAME" IS NULL) 
BEGIN
  SELECT table_seq.nextval
  INTO :new."COLUMNNAME" 
  FROM dual;
END;
/
```